# ANTLR4 catch an entire line of arbitrary data

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar with command lines starting with a / and "data lines" which is everything that does not start with a slash.

I just can't get it to be parsed correctly, the following rule

`FM_DATA: ( ('\r' | '\n' | '\r\n') ~'/') -> mode(DATA_MODE);`

does almost what I need but for a data line of

`abcde`

the following tokens are generated

```
[@23,170:171='\na',<4>,4:72]
[@24,172:175='bcde',<103>,5:1]
```

so the first character is swallowed by the rule.

I also tried

```
FM_DATA: ( {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? ~'/') -> mode(DATA_MODE);
```

but this causes even weirder things.

What's the correct rule for getting this to work as expected ?

TIA - Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `... -> more` command can be used to let the first char (or first part of a lexer rule) not be consumed (yet).

A quick demo:

```
lexer grammar FmDataLexer;

NewLine
 : [\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

CommandStart
 : '/' -> pushMode(CommandMode)
 ;

FmDataStart
 : . -> more, pushMode(FmDataMode)
 ;

mode CommandMode;

 CommandLine
  : ~[\r\n]+ -> popMode
  ;

mode FmDataMode;

 FmData
  : ~[\r\n]+ -> popMode
  ;
```

If you run the following code:

```java
FmDataLexer lexer = new FmDataLexer(CharStreams.fromString("abcde\n/mu"));
CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
stream.fill();

for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
  System.out.printf("%-20s '%s'\n", FmDataLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()), t.getText());
}
```

you'll get this output:

```
FmData               'abcde'
CommandStart         '/'
CommandLine          'mu'
EOF                  '<EOF>'
```

See: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#mode-pushmode-popmode-and-more

Comment: Simple and elegant, thanks !

As command lines aren't to be consumed in full but tokenized / parsed (of course) I had to add the following to pop back to default mode from CommandMode, I hope this is the proper way of doing it
    
`EOL: ( [ ]* ('\r' | '\n' | '\r\n') ) -> popMode;`

Comment: Q2:
    
I am not interested in any parameters for some commands.
 
For single line commands I simply let it switch to "DataMode".

A continuation is denoted by a hyphen at the end of the line + another slash starting the following, for verbosely parsed commands I simply concatenate with `CONTINUE : ( '-' [ ]* ('\r/' | '\n/' | '\r\n/') ) -> channel(HIDDEN);`

When I switch to "DataMode" for e.g. `/ COMMAND1 KEY1=val1, -` `/ KEY2=val2` the "parse any until EOL" rule swallows the hyphen and the 2nd line is seen as a new command rather than a continuation.

Is this solvable ?

Comment: "... proper way of doing it ...", looks fine to me

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean with certain things in Q2. I recommend you create a new question for that one. In a question you can elaborate a bit more, which is not really possible in these small comment boxes.

Comment: Right, I was about to create a new question with Lexer + Parser + example for Q2 anyway.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70742427/antlr4-handling-continuations-for-any-data) we go