# ANTLR4 handling continuations for "any data"

Tags: antlr4

The grammar I need to create  is based on the following:

1. Command lines start with a slash
2. Command lines can be continued with a hyphen as the last character
   (excluding whitespaces) on a line
3. For some commands I want to parse their parameters
4. For other commands I am not interested in their parameters

This works almost fine with the following (simplified) Lexer

```
lexer grammar T1Lexer;

NewLine
 : [\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

CommandStart
 : '/' -> pushMode(CommandMode)
 ;

DataStart
 : . -> more, pushMode(DataMode)
 ;

mode DataMode;

 DataLine
  : ~[\r\n]+ -> popMode
  ;

mode CommandMode;

  CmNL
  : [\r\n]+ -> skip, popMode
  ;

  CONTINUEMINUS :     ( '-' [ ]* ('\r/' | '\n/' | '\r\n/') ) -> channel(HIDDEN);
  EOL: ( [ ]* ('\r' | '\n' | '\r\n') ) -> popMode;

  SPACE :        [ \t\r\n]+    -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
  DOT :          [.] ;
  COMMA :        ',' ;

  CMD1 :        'CMD1';
  CMD2 :        'CMD2';
  CMDIGN :      'CMDIGN' -> pushMode(DataMode) ;

  VAR1 :        'VAR1=' ;

  ID :                  ID_LITERAL;

fragment ID_LITERAL:                 [A-Z_$0-9]*?[A-Z_$]+?[A-Z_$0-9]*;
```

and Parser:

```
parser grammar T1Parser;

options { tokenVocab=T1Lexer; }

root :  line+ EOF   ;

line:   ( commandLine | dataLine)+  ;

dataLine :  DataLine    ;

commandLine :   CommandStart command    ;

command : cmd1 | cmd2 | cmdign ;

cmd1 :    CMD1 (VAR1 ID)+ ;
cmd2 :    CMD2 (VAR1 ID)+ ;
cmdign :    CMDIGN DataLine ;
```

[image: Test data]

The problem arises where I need a combination of 2. + 4., i.e. continuation for a command where I want to simply get the parms as an unparsed String (lines 5+6 in the example).

When I push to DataMode for CMDIGN on line 5 the continuation character is not recognized as it is swallowed by the "any until EOL" rule, so I pop back to default mode and the continuation line is considered a new command and fails to parse.

Is there a way of handling this combo properly ?

TIA - Alex

[image: Tokens]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For your example) You don't really need a `CommandMode`; it actually complicates things a bit.

T1Lexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar T1Lexer
    ;

CMD_START: '/';

CONTINUE_EOL_SLASH: '-' EOL_F '/' -> channel(HIDDEN);
EOL:                EOL_F;

WS:    [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
DOT:   [.];
COMMA: ',';

CMD1:   'CMD1';
CMD2:   'CMD2';
CMDIGN: 'CMDIGN' -> pushMode(DataMode);

VAR1: 'VAR1=';

ID: ID_LITERAL;

//=======================================
mode DataMode
    ;

DM_EOL:    EOL_F -> type(EOL), popMode;
DATA_LINE: ( ~[\r\n]*? '-' EOL_F)* ~[\r\n]+;

//=======================================
fragment NL:         '\r'? '\n';
fragment EOL_F:      [ ]* NL;
fragment ID_LITERAL: [A-Z_$0-9]*? [A-Z_$]+? [A-Z_$0-9]*;
```

T1Parser.g4

```
parser grammar T1Parser
    ;

options {
    tokenVocab = T1Lexer;
}

root: line (EOL line)* EOL? EOF;

line: commandLine | dataLine | emptyLine;

dataLine: DATA_LINE;

commandLine: CMD_START command;

emptyLine: CMD_START;

command: cmd1 | cmd2 | cmdign;

cmd1:   CMD1 (VAR1 ID)+;
cmd2:   CMD2 (VAR1 ID)+;
cmdign: CMDIGN DATA_LINE?;
```

Test Input:

```
/ CMD1 VAR1=VAL1 VAR1=VAL2
/ CMDIGN VAR1=BLAH VAR2=BLAH
/ CMD2 VAR1=VAL12 -
/      VAR1=VAL22
/ CMDIGN
/
/ CMDIGN VAR-1=0 -   
/        VAR2=notignored
```

Token Stream:

```
[@0,0:0='/',<'/'>,1:0]
[@1,1:1=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:1]
[@2,2:5='CMD1',<'CMD1'>,1:2]
[@3,6:6=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:6]
[@4,7:11='VAR1=',<'VAR1='>,1:7]
[@5,12:15='VAL1',<ID>,1:12]
[@6,16:16=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:16]
[@7,17:21='VAR1=',<'VAR1='>,1:17]
[@8,22:25='VAL2',<ID>,1:22]
[@9,26:26='\n',<EOL>,1:26]
[@10,27:27='/',<'/'>,2:0]
[@11,28:28=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:1]
[@12,29:34='CMDIGN',<'CMDIGN'>,2:2]
[@13,35:54=' VAR1=BLAH VAR2=BLAH',<DATA_LINE>,2:8]
[@14,55:55='\n',<EOL>,2:28]
[@15,56:56='/',<'/'>,3:0]
[@16,57:57=' ',<WS>,channel=1,3:1]
[@17,58:61='CMD2',<'CMD2'>,3:2]
[@18,62:62=' ',<WS>,channel=1,3:6]
[@19,63:67='VAR1=',<'VAR1='>,3:7]
[@20,68:72='VAL12',<ID>,3:12]
[@21,73:73=' ',<WS>,channel=1,3:17]
[@22,74:76='-\n/',<CONTINUE_EOL_SLASH>,channel=1,3:18]
[@23,77:82='      ',<WS>,channel=1,4:1]
[@24,83:87='VAR1=',<'VAR1='>,4:7]
[@25,88:92='VAL22',<ID>,4:12]
[@26,93:93='\n',<EOL>,4:17]
[@27,94:94='/',<'/'>,5:0]
[@28,95:95=' ',<WS>,channel=1,5:1]
[@29,96:101='CMDIGN',<'CMDIGN'>,5:2]
[@30,102:102='\n',<EOL>,5:8]
[@31,103:103='/',<'/'>,6:0]
[@32,104:104='\n',<EOL>,6:1]
[@33,105:105='/',<'/'>,7:0]
[@34,106:106=' ',<WS>,channel=1,7:1]
[@35,107:112='CMDIGN',<'CMDIGN'>,7:2]
[@36,113:150=' VAR-1=0 -   \n/
```

tree output:

```
(root 
  (line 
    (commandLine 
      / 
      (command 
        (cmd1 CMD1 VAR1= VAL1 VAR1= VAL2)
      )
    )
  ) 
  \n 
  (line 
    (commandLine 
      / 
      (command 
        (cmdign CMDIGN  VAR1=BLAH VAR2=BLAH)
      )
     )
    ) 
  \n 
  (line 
    (commandLine 
      / 
      (command 
        (cmd2 CMD2 VAR1= VAL12 VAR1= VAL22)
      )
    )
  ) 
  \n 
  (line 
    (commandLine 
      / 
      (command 
        (cmdign CMDIGN)
      )
    )
  ) 
  \n 
  (line 
    (emptyLine /)
  ) 
  \n 
  (line 
    (commandLine 
      / 
      (command 
        (cmdign CMDIGN  VAR-1=0 -   \n/        VAR2=notignored)
      )
    )
  ) 
  <EOF>
)
```

Comment: This sounds straightforward, thanks !

However, for some strange reason not obvious to me it doesn't handle single-line ignored commands properly and pulls in everything until the end of the **last** multi-line ignored command

`[@11,29:34='CMDIGN',<CMDIGN>,2:2]
[@12,35:77=' VAR1=BLAH VAR2=BLAH\n/ CMD2 VAR1=VAL12   -\n',<DataLineCont>,2:8]
[@13,78:113='/      VAR1=VAL22\n/ CMDIGN VAR1=0 -\n',<DataLineCont>,4:0]
[@14,114:140='/        VAR2=NOTIGNORED -\n',<DataLineCont>,6:0]
[@15,141:162='/        VAR3=DONTCARE',<DataLine>,7:0]
[@16,164:164='/',<CommandStart>,8:0]`

Comment: Ah, yeah, missed that.  the DataLine_Cont rule was too greedy.  I've modified it.

Comment: Thanks, better but still not there, I'm afraid

As soon as a dash appears as part of the "data" it flips back from DataLine_Cont to DataLine, e.g.

`/ CMDIGN KEY-1=VAL1 -` `/ KEY2=VAL2`

Comment: yeah, over corrected, should not have had the '-' in the exclude set at the beginning of DataLine_Cont.

Comment: Two additional / final problems popped up ... when no parameters are specified for CMDIGN, cos' they are optional, the command switches to DataMode and leaves me with `token recognition error at: '\n'`, the same happens with empty DataLines.

Comment: A quick look indicates that this has to do with the unusual way you're handling EOL and the fact that it creates a situation where you push into `DataMode` and then need to `popMode` without having any recognized tokens.  You can't do that.  I'm a bit busy today, but will update when I get a chance to revisit and work out a solution.

Comment: Mike, first of all a BIG thanks four your time ! Followed by an apology because I somewhat led you the wrong direction :-(

I need a "real data mode" because everything that does NOT start with a slash is a "data line", so while your modified answer works for an "empty command line" with just a slash and nuffin else, it completely drops those that are "data lines" embedded between commands.

Comment: I had suspected that this was a simplified version of something larger (there were clues).  Without a broader specification, it’s difficult to suggest a more specific answer.  Also, StackOverflwo isn’t really the place to post a specification and get an answer.  We want more specific questions/answers.  Feel free to formulate another answer.  If you’d like to collaborate more, maybe a GitHub repo and we can have a discussion.  (BTW, there are a number of things in this grammar that, I don’t believe will scale well, but I tried to stay focused on the changes necessary for your question only.

Comment: I hadn't mentioned that part because it did work ok already, so tried to reduce the example to what's causing problems, but I agree, including all aspects would have made that clear.